# Can noun "миля" have Gen. Pl. form "милей"?

Tags: падежи

In the "Техника – молодежи" magazine, №5 1977, there is a sci-fi story translated from English, "A Task for Emmy", it is about a super-computer called "Эмми". The story has a phrase that puzzled me, "тысячи **милей** ее проводов". All my dictionaries (Dahl, Ushakov, Ozhegov, Zaliznyak) say "миля" is the 1st declension soft variant, that is the genitive case plural should be "миль", like "пуля – пуль". What is that "милей" form? Can that be an archaic/regional variant? Or is it just a mere typo or the translator's mistake? I have been reading "Техника – молодежи" for all my life and so far I have never seen even a single typo in it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it feels almost like cheating but once again Google Ngram Viewer [turns out](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%2C%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0) to be a nice research tool at least for getting started:[image]

So, it's actually pretty clear that `милей` never was as popular as `миль`. Which is actually kinda strange, since there's no obvious reason for this. In wiktionary it is [mentioned](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F), that in Zaliznyak's classification `миля` belongs to [type 2a](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C:%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0) - that means "слова с основой на мягкий согласный, ударение всегда на основу" - but, say `тюлень`, `олень` or even pretty rare `киль`  do not follow that pattern.

Comment: I wonder if when doing the corpus search there's a way to separate _милей_, the gen. pl. of _миля_, from its omograph _милей_, which is the comparative degree of the adjective _милый_.

Comment: @YellowSky yes, it's tricky, but  since Count(милей (Gen. миля) + милей (adjective)) > Count(милей (Gen. миля)) and is still pretty low - it's still worth to rely on chart  in this particular case.

Comment: Found it! [Here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=89NUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA316&dq="милей"&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio1v7ktr_UAhVoCZoKHdzWAlMQ6AEIXTAH#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&f=false), starting from page 315 and on. Printed in 1850.

Comment: `but, say тюлень, олень or even pretty rare киль do not follow that pattern` Well, that's because they belong to the masculine gender ;-) "Миля" is regular _feminine_ 2a, just like "неделя".

Comment: Never paid attention, but that's really interesting. Say, миля will be миль, but доля – долей. Why?

Comment: @V.V. - _Доля_ belongs to Zaliznyak declension type _ж 2е_ which means that in the plural the stress shifts to the case ending, and if the gen. pl. ending is stressed, it cannot be zero, like in _миль, пуль_, it must be _-ей_, that is _долéй_, according to Zaliznyak.

Comment: @YellowSky very nice and interesting find!

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed not grammatical. It may be a regional form from the place the author was from, but not standard Russian. By the way, Google search has got 162 for "тысяча милей" whilst  20k for "тысяча миль".